# Jenkins - monitoring the estimated time of builds

Tags: jenkins

I would like to monitor the estimated time of all of my builds to catch the cases where this value is shown as 'N/A'. 
In these cases the build gets stuck (probably due to network issues in my environment) and it won't start new builds for that job until killed manually.

What I am missing is how to get that data for each job, either from api or other source.

I would appreciated any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For each job, you can click "Trend" on the job run history table, and it will show you the currently executing progress along with a graph of "usual" execution times.

Using the API, you can go to `http://jenkins/job/<your_job_name>/<build_number>/api/xml` (or `/json`) and the information is under `<duration>` and `<estimatedDuration>` fields.

Finally, there is a [**Jenkins Timeout Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) that you can use to automatically take care of "stuck" builds

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already use the Timeout Plugin with the 'Abort the build if it's stuck' flag on, but yet sometimes I find builds stuck. I wonder how will the <duration> and <estimatedDuration> values will differ in stuck builds from normal builds. I couldn't find any difference.

Comment: Depends on what you consider "stuck". You could say that if "duration" is twice as long as "estimatedDuration", then it's stuck